# UFT Export Result viewer Steps grafics

Tags: hp-uft

There is a way to export the grafis en UFT like this [Example](http://rossoneill.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/HP-Run-Results-Viewer.png)

i only could exports the steps result but i want to export the graphics to send by email